# oracle trigger with error

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm new in programming and I'm not good at it, so please help me with the next problem:

I have this trigger:

```
begin
if (:new.POLUARE LIKE '%W%' 
    OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZA%' 
    OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZD%' 
    OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZG%' 
    OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZJ%') AND SUBSTR(NR_REGISTR,1,1)='A'
`    `:new.INCERCARE:='NEDC';
end if;  
end;
```

I get the following error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
* & - + / at mod remainder rem then <an exponent (**)> and or || multiset

The symbol "then" was substituted for "" to continue.
```

Comment: Are those backticks part of your original code, or did they wind up in the question while you tried to format it?

Comment: An `IF` requires a `THEN`. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#GUID-1D6FD34F-F58B-4D0B-B7FC-F7C2C22377C3

Comment: PL/SQL uses the `then` keyword to terminate `if` conditions (`if x then y; end if;`) where some other languages use brackets (`if (x) y;`) You don't need both.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
begin
if ( (:new.POLUARE LIKE '%W%' 
         OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZA%' 
         OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZD%' 
         OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZG%' 
         OR :new.POLUARE LIKE '%ZJ%')
      AND SUBSTR(NR_REGISTR,1,1)='A')
then :new.INCERCARE := 'NEDC';
end if;  
end;
```

I think you had a problem with parentheses encapsulating your `OR`'s.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had a problem at SUBSTR (NR_REGISTR, 1.1), it had to be SUBSTR (: new.NR_REGISTR, 1.1).

Once again, thank you very much.